# Installs Data to Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to pull Play Console installs Data to Google sheets, I have tried different variation but not working.

```
function getPlayConsoleData() {
  var packageName = "com.package.myapp"; // Replace with your package name
  var dateRange = "LAST_30_DAYS"; // Replace with the desired date range (e.g. LAST_7_DAYS, LAST_30_DAYS)
  var reportUrl = "https://play.google.com/apps/publish/api/developer/" + packageName + "/statistics/installs?date_range=" + dateRange;
  
  var options = {
    headers: {
      "Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()
    }
  };
  
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(reportUrl, options);
  var json = response.getContentText();
  var data = JSON.parse(json);
  
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1"); // Replace with your sheet name
  sheet.clearContents(); // Clear previous data
  
  var rows = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var row = [
      data[i].date,
      data[i].packageName,
      data[i].dailyDeviceInstalls,
      data[i].dailyDeviceUninstalls,
      data[i].dailyDeviceUpgrades,
      data[i].totalUserInstalls,
      data[i].dailyUserInstalls,
      data[i].dailyUserUninstalls,
      data[i].activeDeviceInstalls,
      data[i].installEvents,
      data[i].updateEvents,
      data[i].uninstallEvents
    ];
    rows.push(row);
  }
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, rows.length, rows[0].length).setValues(rows);
}


I tried moving it to active sheet but I dont think the error is related to that.
```

Error    SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON getPlayConsoleData    @ Ch.gs:14"